# Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/etc/resolv.conf'

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/etc/resolv.conf'

I think this error message suggests a dns lookup, but I don't have any DNS lookups in my code that I am aware of.

I thought maybe to set a breakpoint and look at the stack trace, but I would have to set a breakpoint in node core modules like fs or dns, is that even possible?

How can I determine where in the code this error is being thrown?

Update as per request from @ChatterOne:

Relevant code:

```
const db = dbClient.db(dbName);

debug(`Droping mongo db ${dbName} at address ${dbClient.address}`);

db.dropDatabase(function(err, results) {
  if (err) { // <--- Never reached when wifi connections is off
    return callback(err);
  }
  debug(`Dropped database complete: ${dbName}`);
  return callback();
});
```

That's where the exception occurs, but it only occurs when my wifi connection is off.

Note that db connection is using [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native).

Comment: Is there no call stack in the error? Just that message?

Comment: There is no call stack in the error, only the error message

Comment: I found a way to get node to output debug info by setting NODE_DEBUG, but there was only connections to 127.0.0.1, nothing indicating dns lookup

Comment: In case it's useful to others it was from this article https://www.alxolr.com/articles/debugging-tools-and-practices-in-node-js#debug-nodejs-internals-with-node_debug

Comment: I added a handler for uncaughtException events and the exception that gets passed to the handler has stack set to "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/etc/resolv.conf'" - Is that normal? Shouldn't there be a stack trace?

Comment: You should at least post the code generating the exception

Comment: @ChatterOne Updated question as requested. Any ideas?

Comment: @ChatterOne I just updated the code snippet (previous update was old code)

Comment: I created a minimal express app that only does the db connection and db.dropDatabase in the same way I have in my real code and the problem doesn't surface when wifi is off. So I'm not convinced that the issue is with the db.dropDatabase command.

Comment: It would be great if there was a way to break on any error in the debugger like how devtools works in the browser. I can't think of any way to debug this ENOENT issue. Figuring out where an exception is occurring shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: Is there perhaps some other unixy tool I can run and see if the process is attempting to make a dns/network request?